# Status line group constant width

Tags: vimrc, statusline

I have this in my `vimrc` for setting the status line:

```
set laststatus=2
set statusline=%3(%{mode()}\ %)
set statusline+=%1*\ %F
```

For `normal` and `visual` mode (but also for all other modes tested):

[image: Normal]
[image: Visual Line]

But for `visual block` and `select block` mode, the display is broken: the trailing space is not displayed with the same color:

[image: Visual Block]

What is the issue here?

Comment: `mode()` returns a literal `Ctrl-V` for visual block mode and a literal `Ctrl-S` for select mode. You should write a custom function that cleans up the output of `mode()` instead of `mode()` directly.

Comment: This seems to solve the issue, if you want to make an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mode()` returns a literal `Ctrl-V` for visual block mode and a literal `Ctrl-S` for select mode.

You should write a custom wrapper around `mode()` to avoid side effects.